# Pasar una tabla desde SqlAlchemy a un html flask

Tags: html, python, flask, sqlalchemy

mi problema es este, la cosa es que tengo una tabla con asignaturas como puede ser álgebra , calculo , etc y tengo hacer elegir al usuario una de estas pero no se como sacar todos los nombres de la tabla para pasarlo a una lista y enviarlo al html para después de eso mostrar un input de tipo radio y elija una de las asignaturas.

Codigo flask:

```
@app.route('/evaluacion', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def evaluacion():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        asignatura = request.form['materia']
        return redirect( url_for('profesor', asignatura=asignatura ))

    ramos = Asignatura.query.filter_by().all()
    return render_template('ramos.html', ramos = ramos )
```

Codigo html:

```
   <form action="http://localhost:5000/evaluacion">
        {% for {name} in ramos %}
            name <input type="radio" name="asignatura" value="{{ name }}">
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
```

La verdad tampoco se si la parte del html esta bien, ya que soy un completo noob en el tema. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este segmento de codigo

```
<form action="http://localhost:5000/evaluacion">
    {% for {name} in ramos %}
        name <input type="radio" name="asignatura" value="{{ name }}">
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

La variable "name" es un diccionario con las propiedades de su tabla en la base de datos, por lo que para asignar el nombre de la signatura como valor del radio y asumiendo que esa propiedad de la tabla tenga por nombre **name** entonces debe cambiar el value de esto:

```
value="{{ name }}"
```

a esto:

```
value="{{ name.name }}"
```

y para mostrar el nombre de la asignatura a un lado del radio debe cambiar su código HTML de esto:

```
name <input type="radio" name="asignatura" value="{{ name }}">
```

a esto:

```
{{name.name}} <input type="radio" name="asignatura" value="{{ name.name }}">
```

Comment: gracias era eso y tambien quite los "{}" en el bucle for que estan de mas me ayudaste muchisimo